# In converting to chomsky, can i simplify the unit production S->Z of this language?

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, chomsky-normal-form

```
S -> wZx | WyX | Z | yX | Wy | y 
W -> wW | w
X -> xX | x 
Z -> zZ | z
```

Making it

```
S -> wZx | WyX | zZ | z| yX | Wy | y 
W -> wW | w
X -> xX | x
```

is just wrong. So i'm wondering if this unit production should just stay as it is

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's not wrong as long as you leave the Z -> zZ | z rules in the grammar (otherwise you have a non-terminal Z with no rules). It is, however, only one small step in converting to Chomsky normal form.

Comment: @ChrisDodd but wouldn't it be ambiguous?

Comment: @prestize: no, it would not be ambiguous.